# Printer quit working with "Printer Error: Connecting to Device"

Tags: printing

My brother HL-5370DW has worked fine for years with several LTS versions of Ubuntu!! For some reason this last week or so it quit working, giving the error shown in the Title.
I have tried deleting and reinstalling the printer, using every driver option available, none work.  I booted into Windows 10 and it prints fine, so I know its not the printer. I have updated the internet to fiber recently, so have a new modem.  The ethernet cable goes from the modem to the printer (and another cable to the desktop).  It seems to find the printer just fine when I "add a new printer" and select Network printer.
I found by trial and error I can get ubuntu to print if I give it the IP address.  Read somewhere that is not a good idea..it might change when I reboot or something..
is there something else I should try?